# CMake error in hector_navigation or navigation

Tags: ros, navigation, hector-navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! I'm using a RPi2 with Ubuntu and ROS Indigo (desktop). I am trying to install hector_navigation:

```
cd catkin_ws/src
git clone https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_navigation.git
catkin_make
```

but at this point I get this error message:

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:75 (find_package):
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "pcl_conversions"
with any of the following names:

pcl_conversionsConfig.cmake
pcl_conversions-config.cmake

Add the installation prefix of "pcl_conversions" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
set "pcl_conversions_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.
If "pcl_conversions" provides a separate development package or SDK, be
sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
hector_navigation/hector_costmap/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Invoking "cmake" failed
```

I had got the same problem too by installing navigation from https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation.git.
How do I fix? Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228415/cmake-error-in-hector_navigation-or-navigation/) by [papaclaudia](https://answers.ros.org/users/25634/papaclaudia/) on ROS Answers with karma: 94 on 2016-03-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This error says that the package [pcl_conversions](http://wiki.ros.org/pcl_conversions) is missing.
Install it by hand or use the very useful [rosdep tool](http://wiki.ros.org/rosdep). (Not sure if it works on a RPi)

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2016-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [papaclaudia](https://answers.ros.org/users/25634/papaclaudia/) on 2016-03-07**:
Thank you! I have just one more question for you: with "install it by hand" do you mean always doing from "github.com..."?

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2016-03-07**:
No. You should only install a package from source (from github.com...) if you have reasons to do it. If you just want to use the package then installing it via `sudo apt-get install ...` should be preferred.

**Comment by [papaclaudia](https://answers.ros.org/users/25634/papaclaudia/) on 2016-03-08**:
Hi! I tried doing "sudo apt-get update" and then "sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-pcl-conversions" but I get "Enable to locate packages...". How can I do?